# How do I change the path of Python 3.5 test to 2.7 in executing Automated tests?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, python-2.7, automation

Newbie here. The background is that I am using GIT and have access to repositories from remote.  Here is the problem: The repositories Python folders use 2.7 Syntax.  When I execute by automation, I get this error (which is a 2.7 to 3.5 issue)

```
ERROR: Failure: SyntaxError (Missing parentheses in call to
'print' (test_controller.py, line 368))
```

This error tells me that its a Python syntax issue.  The rest of the results follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File '/home/myName/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nose/

failure.py', line 39, in runTest
```

So based on this result, I find out that it's using Python 3.5 syntax to check the repositories, but the python files in the repositories I have access to, are using 2.7 Syntax.

So how can I change the path/directories to use Python 2.7 syntax checking?

Update (1)

```
which python
```

gives me `/usr/bin/python`

Update (2) This is my .bashrc file if helpful.   I'll still troubleshoot this of course and check thoroughly.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
     *i*) ;;
       *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt 
below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; 
turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal 
window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
# We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
# (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
# a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
color_prompt=yes
else
color_prompt=
fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\
[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
 *)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || 
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export 

GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:
locus=01:quote=01'

export PYTHON_PATH="/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python"
export PYTHONBASE="/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python"
export TEST_CONFIG_FILE="/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python"

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo 
terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-
9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly, but please in general do not make any changes to global python configuration. Usually if you want python 3, you call `python3`. If you've already changed something, that may be the cause of your issues...

Comment: Hello, yeah, sorry for the vagueness.  I use git 'clone' to obtain repositories needed for automation.  These repositories have python folders, were the python syntax in all of them are 2.7, where as, when I automate, it looks into my .local directory where Python 3.5 is located, and gives me syntax error because its looking at the repositories python folders, and checking for 3.5 syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to change the PATH variabled exported in your .bashrc file (which is located in your home directory). For example, mine contains:

```
export PATH="/home/max/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

Because I'm using an anaconda version of python. If you get rid of this, it should go back to the built-in version, which I think is 2.7. 
Can you post the contents of your .bashrc file?

Edit: if you execute the following:

```
which python
```

in terminal it should show you where the python 3.5 is; look for something with that directory in your .bashrc file

Comment: Hello, for my .bashrc file, the only export paths I had were:  PYTHON_PATH="/home/myname/Automation/pdci_keyword/python" , I also have PYTHONBASE and TEST_CONFIG_FILE that share same path as the PYTHON PATH.  With my .profile, it has     :export PATH=$PATH:/home/myName   I'll update you, new to posting here.

Comment: Try putting a # in front of that line (the python_path one) in .bashrc (always make a backup of .bashrc when editing it, just in case), saving it, opening a new terminal window, and starting python.

Comment: Tried, still testing.  Thanks for commenting though, if I can't figure this out by end of day, i'll have to ask the leading project person to help me out.  But appreciate the help

Comment: Good luck; one last thing that may be useful to try is see what version of python is in /usr/bin/python. In other words open a window and type:

/usr/bin/python

If python launches (it should, I think that's where Ubuntu puts its default version) it will say what version it is. If that's the right one, you could try putting an alias to /usr/bin/python in your .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

just to update - I have asked my project leader and the leader has no clue how to fix the path issue.  Also asked co-workers and not a definite help.

So here is what I will do: I will use '2to3' converter that will allow me to change all the python repositories folder, into python 3 syntax.  Not much of a hassle, experimenting and making sure i have backup repository files incase something does go awry.

Thanks for the answer/comments though, am fairly new to both linux/python, so this was a bit overwhelming to fix! I will checkmark the 1st answer response, and resolve this topic.  I will create a new topic should some other error pop up.